# How to search for formatted text in EPUB?

Tags: search, formatting, epub

When reading a book, I add it to the catalog on one of the book cataloging websites. Then I go through the book's bibliography and mark all mentioned books "to-read". Sometimes bibliography is a dedicated section, but it is not always the case. I recently read an EPUB book mentioning other books inside the text body. The only emphasis was the italic text. How do I search for all italics in the EPUB book?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What is your EPUB reader?

Comment: I use Books application for Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Take the following steps:

1. Convert your EPUB to HTML. It's possible to do it online, try searching for a dedicated website.
2. Download and open the HTML file using a text editor.
3. Find a formatted text fragment you know.
4. Discover its way to become formatted. In my case, I had the following tag surrounding it: `<i class="calibre3">...</i>`.
5. Search for the formatting. In the example above, I would use the `<i class="calibre3">` search text.